# Plist in a table view cell

Tags: swift

I just finished a course on swift today and desided to start to write code so I can learne it more there's a lot of stuff on the complete iOS course that were not covered. What I'm after I can only find in objective c as I might be typing it wrong

I have a made a tap view app and on the scond tab I have conect a nav controller that then conects to a table view with a cell. I have identified it with "cell"

I also have a plist that's made up with names that I want it to attach to. And either I'm thick or just to new.

Any help would be great and sorry if I'm doing this wrong

Comment: I did try this let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Systems", ofType:"plist")